# Youtube etc. video problem

Tags: windows-7, windows

I get corrupted video on Youtube and BBC iPlayer in Windows 7, in all browsers.  They used to work OK, but not now. They work fine in Safe Mode and in Virtual XP Mode, so I imagine that something is causing a conflict, but I am tearing my hair out trying to find it!  I have reinstalled Flash Player, Active X, etc. to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between safe mode/Virtual XP mode and your normal runtime is the drivers. In Virtual XP it uses a software renderer and in safe mode it uses basic vga drivers. Try reinstalling or updating the graphics card drivers